# What should be in a cover letter for a mini course/summer school application?

Tags: application, application-cover-letter

I'm a graduate student in STEM applying for some mini-courses and summer schools, most ask for a cover letter. I haven't done much research yet as a grad student yet, and the projects I am working on aren't really related to what will be covered in these courses.

I've done a fair amount of coursework that relates to the topics that will be covered in this courses, and I'll mention that, but I'm not sure what else they want to hear about. What else should go in a cover letter for this kind of application?

Comment: If the course isn't related to your research, then why *do* you want to attend the course? Presumably you have some reason, so use the cover letter to explain it.